# Disable IMX UART on Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, uart, imx6

I have an IMX mcu connected to a WL1387 Bluetooth chip via UART. I have another device connected to the same UART which I would like to use for a test setup. I noticed that the IMX is holding the UART line high.

Is there anyway to disable to UART line from the IMX side?

Thanks

Comment: To permanently disable it you could remove support from the device tree/board file if you can compile the kernel. Otherwise I'm sure the `stty` command will probably allow you to configure it how you want.

Comment: I only want to temporarily disable while the program is running